# Промотать до конца RecyclerView, когда нажал на edittext

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-edittext

Нужно, чтобы сообщения в RecyclerView были промотаны до конца, при нажатии на EditText. Сейчас происходит по другому, когда раскрывается клавиатура, часть сообщений остается под ней и пользователю приходится проматывать пальцем до них.

[image: Вот здесь клавиатура скрыта]

[image: Здесь клавиатура раскрыта и она накладывается на чат, что не должно быть]

[image: И вот как должно быть]

Как это можно сделать? Какой-то атрибут? Или строчка кода. Проматывать программно recyclerView не выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перемещения в конец списка при выдвижении клавиатуры по "классической" схеме -
 список заполняется сверху вниз, при выдвижении клавиатуры происходит смещение позиций списка в конец. При добавлении элементов, когда весь экран занят, новые уходят за экран снизу (не скролится к последней позиции при добавлении)

Для такого поведения нужно назначить слушатель на размер виджета и при изменении размеров перемещать позицию в конец:

```
recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                if (bottom < oldBottom) recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
            }
        });
```

при желании это перемещение можно анимировать, чтобы сильно не "дергалось".

Однако, поскольку у вас чат, как можно понять из скриншотов, возможно вам больше подойдет следующее поведение - элементы заполняются снизу списка и по мере добавления уходят вверх. При раскрытии клавиатуры видимой останется последняя видимая позиция и сколько войдет выше ее.

Это реализуется всего одной строчкой и управляется лэйаут-менеджером:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

PS: чтобы при добавлении айтемов в список всегда была видима последняя позиция, нужно после операции добавления данных перемещать список вниз на последний элемент:

```
insertData(data);
recyclerView.notifiDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте установить в манифесте у Вашей активити такой атрибут

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю надо менять разметку, так что бы bottom граница RecyclerView ориентировался на bottom родительского окна. RecyclerView не прокручивается из-за того что и так уже прокручен, а клавиатура перекрывает. Надо сделать так что бы клавиатура поднимала нижнюю границу RecyclerView.