# Как сделать открытие recyclerView с конца?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Я сделал клиент по обмену сообщениями, в котором сообщения отображаются при помощи recyclerView, но список открывается в самом начале(наверху), а мне надо, чтобы открывался с конца(снизу), как во всех мессенджерах

Comment: вот [еще ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808173/177345), который вам возможно поможет решить некоторые нюансы при создании списка сообщений

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте свойство reverseLayout в `xml`, там где описывается ваш `RecyclerView`. Оно перевернет ваш RecyclerView.

Через **xml**:

```
app:reverseLayout="true"
app:stackFromEnd="true"
```

Программно:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);                                         
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Надеюсь вам помог мой ответ. 
update исправил ошибку в коде.

Comment: Не помогло( Список все равно открывается с начала

Comment: Обновил ответ    app:stackFromEnd="true"

Comment: Это тоже не помогло

Comment: А как вы делаете программно или через xml?

Comment: Через xml, но сейчас попробую программно

Comment: Программно заработало! Спасибо! Но чтобы все выглядело, так, как мне надо, надо было ещё убрать setReverseLayout

Comment: а вы данные из СУБД берете?

Comment: Получаю с сайта при помощи http запроса

Comment: а у вас с сайта данные идут отсортированные уже по дате?

Comment: Да, уже отсортированные

Comment: Вот поэтому первое свойство не нужно

Answer (score 0):

После присвоения адаптера используйте: 
`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(rv.getAdapter().getItemCount());`

Comment: Это не помогло(